# Converting JavaScript websql to Clojurescript

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript, web-sql

I'm going through a tutorial below

https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html

and am having trouble converting js to cljs in the dataHandler function

```
function dataHandler(transaction, results)
{
// Handle the results
var string = "Green shirt list contains the following people:\n\n";
for (var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
    // Each row is a standard JavaScript array indexed by
    // column names.
    var row = results.rows.item(i);
    string = string + row['name'] + " (ID "+row['id']+")\n";
}
alert(string);
}
```

Here is my cljs code

```
 (defn success-handler [tx, results]
   (println "success handler")
   (println results)

   ;;the below doesn't work, I get an error here  
   ;;:Uncaught Error: [object SQLResultSet] is not ISeqable

  (doseq [result results]
  (prn result)))
```

So my question is how would I convert the js dataHandler to my cljs success-handler?

Answer (score 2):

Try turning the rows of the result into a sequence, rather than the whole result.

```
(defn success-handler [tx, results]
   (println "success handler")
   (println results)

  (doseq [result (.-rows results)]
    (prn result)))
```

And if rows does not implement Iterable then do it the old fashioned way

```
(defn success-handler [tx, results]
   (println "success handler")
   (println results)

  (let [rows (.-rows results)]
   (doall
    (for [i (range (.-length rows))]
      (let [row (nth rows i)]
        (prn result))))))
```

Comment: I believe this is getting me closer to the solution, but when I try both options I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: results.rows is not a function"  My first thought was to create an anon fn outside of ```(.rows results)``` with no luck.

Comment: `rows` is a property not a function, so you need `.-` instead of just `.`

Comment: sorry, yes i forgot to put it in ClojureScript format. I fixed it in the answer

Comment: Is  ```(item i)``` supposed to have ```.-``` in front of ```item```?

Comment: sorry, that was a cut-and-paste fail, it should have been just `i` (I can't actually test this code, so i guess it's more of a guideline)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
(defn success-handler [tx, results]
  (let [rows (.-rows results)]
    (doseq [i (range (.-length rows))]
      (prn (.item rows i)))))
```